# Have the destruction of Olympia and Nostramo been shown in the heresy books?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I am up to slaves to darkness in the Horus heresy series and realized that I haven’t read anything about the iron warriors or nightlords destruction of there own planets. Other than, I believe, a few passing comments or references to them as having happened on the past.

I have missed out a few books in the series so it is possible I have missed them.

Are there any short stories, novellas or chapters of a longer novel that describe the events leading up to, and the destruction itself of these 2 planets. In both cases it was a major contributor to the turning of each legion by Horus. Or do they happen “off page” and are just referenced to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nostramo

The destruction of Nostramo is shown in the short story [The Dark King](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/The_Dark_King_(Short_Story)).

### Olympia

Whilst I don't think Olympia was ever fully destroyed, but him attacking and purging Olympia is in Perturabo's primarch novel [Perturabo: The Hammer of Olympia](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Perturabo:_The_Hammer_of_Olympia_(Novel))